# Variables on advanced matching facebook pixel feature

Tags: facebook, pixel

[FB pixel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raPyO.jpg)

I want to enable the advanced matching feature on facebook pixel. 
The system asks me the variable name for first name, last name, email.

I will get this data from a newsletter form from my wix.com website. I don't know how I can find the variable names to add in the facebook settings. Anybody can help?

Comment: Well first of all you’ll have to figure out whether any such variables actually exist in the first place … This is referring to (global) JavaScript variables, but the service you are using must not necessarily have that data available in such a form to begin with. Maybe you could create them yourself, if you can use custom JS code inside the page, and can read the values from somewhere else (form fields, table showing an overview of entered data, whatever …)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I need to admit that I am not a coder and I don't know anything about java-script unfortunately. How could I create these variables myself? Is it too complex? Any other solution or I should give up?

Comment: As I said, the first step would be to figure out where/how that information is available at all in that confirmation(?) page … If it is present in specific form fields or some other HTML structure, then it could be read form there … but this is all rather in the details.